# JPA managed entities and external updates

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee

just a question about JPA and concurrent external database updates...

Well we are slowly moving our old client-server applications to web-based one by one.

Depending on some decisions not done by me some are being rewritten in Java and some other in .NET MVC.

The techology stack for Java is JavaEE 7 with CDI+EJB and JPA but many have been already rewritten using old JSP technology (they works so won't be rewritten again).

Some databases are shared between the different applications where one of them updates the records and the others only reads (maybe in the future some tables or even fileds may be updated from other apps too).

With JPA our entity beans are not reflecting the state of database records because of session-level cache of managed beans. This is standard JPA behaviour, I know.

I know I can do a `refresh()` on single bean but sometimes there are tens of thousands of them in a collection and reissuing many single-result query (based on PK) instead of extracting e fresh copy of the collection with one single query is a severe performance killer.

Is there any standard JPA annotation or `persistece.xml` parameter to tell JPA to exclude some entities from session-level cache? Or even a query object hint/method to force issuing a new query instead of accessing the session cache (some kind of group invalidation)?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: This is EclipseLink, but the comments about JPA's shared-cache-mode are valid to you: https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Caching

Comment: Thank you but seems that this referers to the second level cache and not to the persistence context cache. a call to `EntityManager#clear()` is not applicable because it will make ALL managed entities to become detached without persisting any changes made to them. What I'm looking for is a collection-wise `refresh()` - not to be done on EVERY single entity or an hint for a query or typedquery to tell JPA to **force** a query again instead of accessing persistence context cache.

Comment: The link I posted wasn't aimed solely at one level of cache as it talks about refresh query hints.  Hints are provider specific, but Hibernate will have an equivalent.  See cacheMode at https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/jpa/QueryHints.html  With it you can refresh the results of any query.